# How can one turn a value of a record type into a JSON String in Haskell?

Tags: json, haskell

Let's say I have record type that looks like this

```
data Person = Person
  { name :: String,
    age
  } deriving (Show)
```

How would I go around turning this into a JSON Object or even String? (I'd like to hash it followingly)

Comment: That's not a typeclass. You mean, _How can one turn a **value of a record type** into a JSON string_?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do this with [the Aeson library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.4.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html). In fact, this is *exactly* the example they give... interesting...

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import GHC.Generics

data Person = Person {
      name :: String
    , age  :: Int
    } deriving (Generic)
instance ToJSON Person

main :: IO ()
main = print $ encode (Person "Luke Morgenstern" 734)
```

Note: if you do this *only for the purpose of calculating a hash*, then JSON is an unneeded and inefficient detour. Better go directly

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Hashable
import GHC.Generics

data Person = Person {
      name :: String
    , age  :: Int
    } deriving (Generic)
instance Hashable Person

main :: IO ()
main = print $ hash (Person "Luke Morgenstern" 734)
```